# Multiple @Input in Ionic 3 and Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, angular2-custom-component

In my Ionic 3 project, I have created custom component my-component.
Now as we know using angular @Input we can pass data to this component.
I have 2 inputs as

```
  @Input('finder') myFinder: Finder; //Finder is an Interface
  @Input('list') myList: Array<any>;
```

I am using this component as

```
<my-component [finder]="dataFinder" [list]="aList"></my-component>
```

Both `dataFinder` and `aList` has value but `myFinder` value is always `undefined` where `myList` is correctly populated.

This the any restriction using multiple inputs?

Comment: No there is no restrictions, please reproduce this issue in a plunker/stackblitz :)

Comment: Sorry guys. It was a miskate from me. I was reading the Input params in the constructor. It should be done after ngAfterViewInit().

Comment: Well, you can do it in OnInit as well, there the input is also available.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you don't need to maintain 2 data bind properties at all. You can do it more elegantly as shown below. Hope code is self-explanatory.

*my-class.ts*

```
export class MyClass{
   finder:Finder;
   myList:Array<any>;   
}
```

*.ts*

```
@Input('data') data: MyClass;
```

*.html*

```
<my-component [data]="data"></my-component>
```